# Placing Printed text in the same line as text before it

Tags: c++

I'm currently making a basic program design to behave somewhat like a chell. The code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),10);
    std::string name;
    std::string pass;
    std::string msg;
    int x = 1;
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "Booting up system..." << endl;
    cout << "Serial Code: " << (rand()%1000) << "." << endl;
    cout << "Username: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    cout << "Password: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, pass);
    cout << "" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        cout<<x<<": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, msg);
        x += 1;

        if (msg == "Hello!"){
        cout << "Hi!" << endl;
        }

        if (msg == ""){
        cout << "[No Text Inserted]" << endl;
    }
    system ("pause");
}
```

And, if no text is input it displays:

```
1:
[No Text Inserted]
```

How do I get this output?

```
1: [No Text Inserted]
```

Thank you in advance!
-DJ

Comment: You need to do it using a library such as [ncurses.](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) As a sidenote, this seems like an unnecessary headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if statements, store the string into a variable and print out in the end. Also if you're comparing the same variable, I recommend using if else statements. It makes it more readable. So:

```
string output;
if (msg == "Hello!)
{
    output = "Hi!";
} 
else if (msg == "")
{
    output = "[No Text Inserted]";
}
output = x.str() + ": " + output;

cout << output << endl;
```

Try that out and let me know if that works.

Comment: This doesn't make it obvious you are waiting for user input.

Comment: Sorry but no, I've just tried it and reformatted it. It seems to experience a problem in the "x.str()" region. Error message: request for member 'str' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'int'

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is remember input cursor position and if the input is empty string, go back to that position and print your fail message, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE conout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Enter something: ";

    // remember cursor position
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    COORD inputPos = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(conout, &info) ? info.dwCursorPosition : COORD{ 0, 0 };

    if (!std::getline(std::cin, input) || input.empty())
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(conout, inputPos);
        std::cout << "[No Text Inserted]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```